# jQuery Full Calendar, all events display as all day

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, iso8601

All of the events for Full Calendar are showing as "all day" in the agenda views.  This is the code that I am using to initialize the calendar :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
            editable: false,
        events: 

                            [{start : $.fullCalendar.parseISO8601('2011-07-01T12:15:00-04:00', true) , end : $.fullCalendar.parseISO8601('2011-07-01T13:15:00-04:00', true) , title : 'Lunch Bunch!- Brookstreet BBQ' , allday : false} , {start : $.fullCalendar.parseISO8601('2011-07-05T17:00:00-04:00', true) , end : $.fullCalendar.parseISO8601('2011-07-05T17:15:00-04:00', true) , title : 'Callback - Gene Cashman' , allday : false} , {start : $.fullCalendar.parseISO8601('2011-07-06T17:00:00-04:00', true) , end : $.fullCalendar.parseISO8601('2011-07-06T17:15:00-04:00', true) , title : 'Callback - Jeff Turner' , allday : false} , {start : $.fullCalendar.parseISO8601('2011-07-20T17:00:00-04:00', true) , end : $.fullCalendar.parseISO8601('2011-07-20T17:15:00-04:00', true) , title : 'Callback - Valley Kidney Center Default Contact' , allday : false} , {start : $.fullCalendar.parseISO8601('2011-07-05T17:00:00-04:00', true) , end : $.fullCalendar.parseISO8601('2011-07-05T17:15:00-04:00', true) , title : 'Callback - Gene Cashman' , allday : false} , {start : $.fullCalendar.parseISO8601('2011-07-01T09:00:00-04:00', true) , end : $.fullCalendar.parseISO8601('2011-07-01T09:15:00-04:00', true) , title : 'Callback - Sandra Wright' , allday : false} , {start : $.fullCalendar.parseISO8601('2011-07-01T09:30:00-04:00', true) , end : $.fullCalendar.parseISO8601('2011-07-01T09:45:00-04:00', true) , title : 'c' , allday : false} , {start : $.fullCalendar.parseISO8601('2011-07-01T15:30:00-04:00', true) , end : $.fullCalendar.parseISO8601('2011-07-01T15:45:00-04:00', true) , title : 'c' , allday : false} , {start : $.fullCalendar.parseISO8601('2011-07-01T16:00:00-04:00', true) , end : $.fullCalendar.parseISO8601('2011-07-01T16:15:00-04:00', true) , title : 'Callback - Linda Cao' , allday : false} , {start : $.fullCalendar.parseISO8601('2011-07-05T09:00:00-04:00', true) , end : $.fullCalendar.parseISO8601('2011-07-05T09:15:00-04:00', true) , title : 'j' , allday : false}]              
        });
    });
```

I'm going to proceed with ajax-ifiying more aspects of the calendar but any help with this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Emily

Answer (score 11):

`allDay` should have a capital `D`.

It's not recognizing `allday` which mean it goes to the default value of `true`.

Comment: @Emily, not a problem. If this answered your question sufficiently, please don't forget to mark it as the accepted answer. You can do that by clicking the checkmark under the up and down arrows. :)

Comment: @Brandon - for new users there is a popup showing this advice when they upvote. :)

Comment: Looks like @Emily vanished in Area 51 so I'll give ya another upvote :-)

Comment: @Brandon She used you